# Prevent overlap between path and node in Tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I'm sure there's some line that spreads nodes out, but I can't find it:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \graph[grow right sep, radius=4cm,
         nodes={circle,draw}] {
         1--2;
         2--3;
         1--3;
         2--4;
         1--4;
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

gives me

[image]

which has an edge blocking node 3.

However, using

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \graph[circular placement, radius=4cm,
         nodes={circle,draw}] {
         1--2;
         2--3;
         1--3;
         2--4;
         1--4;
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

gives me

[image]

which is closer to what I want, but the edges are too long.

Comment: There's a difference between `1 -- 2; 2 -- 3` and `1 -- 2 -- 3`. (Try it out!) Maybe you want `1--2; {3-!-4} --[complete bipartite] {1, 2}`?, The circular placement rules needs to be setup correctly. Usually it is used via `counter clockwise = <number>`. So far you have shown what you don't want. What *do* you want? (And maybe you want to place them nodes manually with coordinates or the `positioning` library? That's still possible!)

Comment: I basically want a graph with the vertices `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`, with the vertices `(1,2), (2,3), (1,3), (2,4)`, and `(1,4)`. I tried to use `positioning` (with the relative `[right=of 3]`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect).

Comment: You need [`no placement`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#tikz/graphs/no:placement) when you go the manual route.